# Databases created from this point onwards read only set to true

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am a beginner at T-SQL. What I need to do is set every database created from this point onwards to be set to read only. I can't seem to find any code online and what I am doing is use

```
ALTER DATABASE model SET READ_ONLY
GO
```

but this only sets the model to read only and any created databases from this point will not be set true.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Why would even want to create a new database if it's **read-only** from the beginning?? What possible use case does this have??

Comment: task i have been assingned : You are to modify your testing database instance, such that any databases which are created
from this point onwards will have their Page Verify option set to None and their Read Only option
set to true. You are to do this using T-SQL and the code be included in the answer file.

Comment: it seems changing model to read only only affect newly created databases

Comment: that's what i need to change read only for the newly created databases which isn't working

Comment: @BenBuhagiar:check this link for the list of options that can be inherited :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388.aspx

Comment: Perhaps a [DDL trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do for system databases (your engine will collapse).

For handling security use `security options`, for rights set `users roles` and `rights`. If you want protect your non-system databases you can use `DDL triggers`.